# "Log In" and "My Account" have vanished from Magento top-links

Tags: magento

I created a new store in magento and made some design changes. Somehow, the "Log In" / "Log Out" and "My Account" top-links are not showing in THAT store... they're showing fine in the other store. "My Wishlist", "My Cart" and "Checkout" are showing fine in all stores. Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Your "design changes" have broken the top-links?

Incidentally, are they *really* not on the page (i.e.: are they visible in the page source)? If so, you most likely have an un-closed element somewhere in the area you've modified.

Comment: Nopes. They are NOT visible in the page source. :(

Comment: @Atriya - In that case you *might* have deleted or commented them out/un-included them in some manner. Why not compare the files you modified with some of the "known good" files on one of the working stores?

Comment: I've searched the layout and template files for every mention of top-links... they all seem the same as the defaults. :( This is really frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide further information?

For example:

- when you are referring to "that" store and the "other" store, are you talking about two store views in the same installation or about two different installations?

- Is it possible that an extension is removing the links in "that" store?

- Is it possible that you are using different languages for the two stores?

Both links belong to the customer module. Maybe there is a difference in the customer settings or (whyever this would be) the Magento customer module is deactivated?

The page source or a URL would be helpful.